# Implementing Thread safe min-priority heap in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, heap, priority-queue

I'm going to implement multithreading in Java where there is one Producer class object, and a number of Consumer class objects. Producer class walks through a given directory and lists files in sorted order of file size. And Consumer class objects will work on those sorted files that has been being updated by Procuder.
What I have planned that: from Producer class I'll create a min-priority heap and the Consumer class will extract value from that heap.
But I can't understand how to implement this approach in Java?
Also, how to make that heap thread-safe?
Please suggest me if there is any better approach.

Comment: Why not use [`PriorityBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html)?

Comment: From what you described you'd have concurrency occurring only among Consumers, as the Producer needs to read the whole directory content before being able to produce the data for the consumers, and once it's done, it's done, i.e. it won't need to update it. Using the suggested data structure might not be the most efficient solution, as you need synchronization only on the pop operations.

Comment: @arshajii... Can you please suggest how I can implement file size as the priority in PriorityBlockingQueue?

Comment: @micantox... In my project, it takes a very long time to list all the files. So, if I wait for full scanning, it will result all the Consumer objects remain idle long time initially. To make those efficient, I thought to do Producer and Consumer work in parallel. That's why I wonder if there is any kind of thread-safe heap in Java.

Comment: Why not start with the simplest approach, see how well it performs, and then only worry about optimization if it does not perform well enough:  I.e., why not just `synchronize` your heap's put() and take() methods?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question then. Do the consumers need to start working from the smallest file in the directory? If that is the case, the Producer will HAVE to read all of the file before the smallest can be known. Or what you meant is just that they need to work on the smallest file found so far (even tho there could be even smaller file left in the directory)?

Comment: @micantox...It's not like that.. I don't need to start with the smallest itself. My target is to complete smaller (not smallest) ones first. So once Producer inserts a reasonable number of files in heap, I can start working with the Consumer.